# How to make a textbox disable but selectable

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

How to make a textbox disable but selectable in C# winform VS 2010?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the ReadOnly property:

```
textbox.ReadOnly = true;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly.aspx